# Using `pgrep` to emulate `ps -ef` for use in a `for i in` loop

Tags: shell, command, ps, pkill

Ubuntu 16.04

I am used to using this command line to kill any process match said COMMAND

```
for i in $(ps -ef | grep COMMAND | awk '{ print $2 }'); do kill -9 "$i" &>/dev/null;done
```

shellcheck does not like it much and suggests

```
root@singa /home # shellcheck run

In run line 4:
for i in $(ps -ef | grep COMMAND | awk '{ print $2 }'); do kill -9 "$i" &>/dev/null;done
           ^-- SC2009: Consider using pgrep instead of grepping ps output.
```

what are the flags needed to complete this here replacing the XXX

```
for i in $(pgrep XXX | grep COMMAND | awk '{ print $2 }'); do kill -9 "$i" &>/dev/null;done
```

I have already checked the man page for pgrep.

Comment: How about just using `pkill` ?  https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill

Comment: Did you even try just running `pgrep COMMAND` before trying to drop it in the place of `ps` in your script?  That should make it clear what has hone wrong with what you did.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I did not. You are correct and I should have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for pid in $(pgrep command); do
    kill -9 $pid
done
```

Or, better yet:

```
pkill -9 command
```

<sub>As a side note, disinterested use of `kill -9` is known to sometimes be the cause of zombie outbreaks, orphaned files, permanent temporary files, and other maladies.  Please instead consider just using `kill` which by default sends `SIGTERM` rather than `SIGKILL`.</sub>

Comment: The  ```for i pid``` command worked well. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i have done below method

```
for i in pickup hald-runner; do pgrep $i | awk '{print "kill" " "  $1}'| sh;done
```

Here pickup,hald-runner is the process names